# Apache airflow,TimeDeltaSensor delays all tasks in the DAG

Tags: airflow

[image]

I have an airflow dag specified as shown in the picture above.
The `git_pull_datagenerator_batch_2` is supposed to be delayed by the TimeDeltaSensor `wait_an_hour`.

However, the task `git_pull_datagenerator` seems to be delayed as well although it does not have a dependency on `wait_an_hour`. (The whole dag is scheduled at 2019-12-10T20:00:00, but git_pull_datagenerator started one hour later than that)

I have checked all documents of airflow but could not find any clues.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your schedule interval is hourly? A DAG run with an execution date of `2019-12-10T20:00:00` on an `@hourly` schedule interval is expected to run at or shortly after `2019-12-10T21:00:00` when hour 20 has "completed". I don't think it has anything to do with the sensor.

This is a [common Airflow pitfall](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/Common+Pitfalls):

> Airflow was developed as a solution for ETL needs. In the ETL world,
>   you typically summarize data. So, if I want to summarize data for
>   2016-02-19, I would do it at 2016-02-20 midnight GMT, which would be
>   right after all data for 2016-02-19 becomes available.

If this is what is happening, `wait_an_hour` started at `2019-12-10T21:00:00` and `git_pull_datagenerator_batch_2` at `2019-12-10T22:00:00`.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the default executor is a SequentialExecutor, which causes all of the tasks to run in a linear order.